# How does JHTML relate to JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to study concepts of dynamic generated web pages with java. I've already studied servlets api. Today I've started to read about JHTML - and I want to understand relationships  between JSP and JHTML. Which of these technologies is more flexible and why? I'm just trying to find optimal way to study these technologies.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JHTML is developed  by Art Technology Group (ATG). It is the **proprietary**  technology that  running on a **special** server called Dynamo created by ATG . Sun licensed this technology from ATG to create the JSP specification.

So , I can see JHTML is a non-standard and older technology than JSP .

See this [white paper](http://www.atg.com/repositories/ContentCatalogRepository_en/white_papers/jhtml_to_jsp020823.pdf) released by ATG in 2002 . It mentions the intertwined History of JHTML and JSP , differences between JHTML and JSP ,and also suggests the advantages to move from JHTML  to JSP. I think you could find your answers in this white paper.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from wiki [jhtml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JHTML)

> JHTML is a proprietary technology of ATG. Sun Microsystems licensed parts of this technology and developed the JSP system from the ATG page compilation system.

And obviously JSP is suitable as it is the java standard.

Answer (score -2):

JHTML works only on ATG application server which is acquired by Oracle back in 2010.  It would be better to stick with standards that are accepted on various application servers.  I agree with dan's advice to stick with JSP, JSF etc.